# How do I make boxes wrap to each other when I resize the screen? (Flexbox)

Tags: html, css, flexbox, responsive

I'm new to the whole concept of responsive design and `flexbox`. How do I make it so that the boxes don't stack on top of each other?

[image: something like this]

```html
<html>

<head>

  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
  <Style>
    .container {
      display: flex;
      flex-wrap: wrap;
    }
    
    .box {
      height: 100px;
      text-align: center;
    }
    
    header {
      width: 100%;
      order: 1;
      background-color: lime
    }
    
    .red {
      width: 50%;
      order: 2;
      background-color: red
    }
    
    .orange {
      width: 50%;
      order: 3;
      background-color: orange
    }
    
    .footer {
      width: 100%;
      order: 4;
      background-color: darkblue
    }
    
    .light_blue {
      width: 20%;
      order: 5;
      background-color: lightblue
    }
    
    .green {
      width: 60%;
      order: 6;
      background-color: green
    }
    
    .light_green {
      width: 20%;
      order: 7;
      background-color: lightgreen
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <header class="box lime">
  </div>
  <div class="box red"></div>
  <div class="box orange"></div>
  <footer class="box dark_blue">
    </div>
    <div class="box light_blue"></div>
    <div class="box green"></div>
    <div class="box light_green"></div>
    </div>


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: you have typos in your code, header is closed as div and footer is also closed as div .. close the element correctly and your code will work fine

Answer (score -2):

`Flexbox` is more oriented to adapt containers to rows when the content is dynamic so you may not know the final width or height.

For your layout I would strongly recommend the use of the classic `float` which is also very easy to manipulate with `mediaqueries` to make it responsive. And your code is ready for it:

```css
* {box-sizing:border-box;}
```

```html
<html>

  <head>

    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <Style>
    .container {
    }
    .box {

      height: 100px;
      text-align: center;
}

    header      {width: 100%;float:left;background-color: lime; }
    .red        {width: 50%;float:left;background-color: red}
    .orange     {width: 50%;float:left;background-color: orange}
    .footer     {width: 100%; float:left;background-color: darkblue}
    .light_blue {width: 20%; float:left;background-color: lightblue}
    .green      {width: 60%; float:left;background-color: green}
    .light_green{width: 20%;float:left;background-color: lightgreen}

    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <header class="box lime"></div>
      <div class="box red"></div>
      <div class="box orange"></div>
      <footer class="box dark_blue"></div>
    <div class="box light_blue"></div>
    <div class="box green"></div>
    <div class="box light_green"></div>
    </div>


  </body>
  </html>
```